# JsDoc renders whole code instead of commented block

Tags: javascript, vue.js, render, documentation, jsdoc

I have a VUE.JS application and we need to documentate it , for .VUE components we decided to go with Vuese but the problem comes for regular JS files such as modules , etc etc we decided to use JsDoc
I installed it and everything is allright but when i generate the HTML files of JsDoc it Renders the WHOLE code and not my commented line

here's an example

```
/** This is a description of the foo function. */
    function myfunction() {
  alert('hello world');
}
console.log(myfunction);
```

and i get this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JSDoc: Source: test.js</title>

    <script src="scripts/prettify/prettify.js"> </script>
    <script src="scripts/prettify/lang-css.js"> </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/prettify-tomorrow.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jsdoc-default.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

    <h1 class="page-title">Source: test.js</h1>

    



 <section>
        <article>
            <pre class="prettyprint source linenums"><code>/** This is a description of the foo function */
function myfunction() {
  alert('hello world');
}
console.log(myfunction);
</code></pre>
        </article>
    </section>

    
    
    
</div>

    <nav>
    <h2><a href="index.html">Home</a></h2><h3>Global</h3><ul><li><a href="global.html#myfunction">myfunction</a></li></ul>
</nav>

<br class="clear">

<footer>
    Documentation generated by <a href="https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc">JSDoc 3.6.7</a> on Thu Jun 24 2021 14:28:24 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)
</footer>

<script> prettyPrint(); </script>
<script src="scripts/linenumber.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What could it be ? or what i am doing wrong?

notes : i installed JsDoc global and i tried both using my jsdocrc.json  and using it alone with the command jsdoc -(PathOfMyJsFile)

TLTR : Basically it is rendering whole code instead of my JsDoc comment

Comment: The comment doesn't look like it follows the jsdoc format? https://jsdoc.app/tags-description.html

Comment: sorry for the late answer but yes it was badly formatted thanks you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As evolutionxbox said the format is wrong ,double check the jsdoc documentation

https://jsdoc.app/tags-description.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30828256)